# Algorithm for independent vertex cover

Tags: algorithm, graph

Question from Skiena book on Algorithm:

A vertex cover of a graph G = (V,E) is a subset of vertices V  ∈ V such that every edge in E contains at least one vertex from V . An independent set of graph G = (V,E) is a subset of vertices V  ∈ V such that no edge in E contains both vertices from V

An independent vertex cover is a subset of vertices that is both an independent set
and a vertex cover of G. Give an efficient algorithm for testing whether G contains
an independent vertex cover. What classical graph problem does this reduce to?

Does anyone know the answer to this question ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

(Need suggestions on this thought)

So far I think this is related to checking whether the graph can be colored using 2 colors, i.e. whether it is bipartite ? If a BFS variant is used to color a graph ,lets say, white and black, then vertices with one of those colors, say white, also forms a vertex cover in some cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thought is correct. It is the problem of checking if a given graph is [bipartite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

Bipartite graphs do not have cycles of odd length, so if you use a BFS to color a graph, the vertices of the same colour will be independent sets.

From Wikipedia:

> If a bipartite graph is connected, its bipartition can be defined by
>   the parity of the distances from any arbitrarily chosen vertex v: one
>   subset consists of the vertices at even distance to v and the other
>   subset consists of the vertices at odd distance to v.
>
> Thus, one may efficiently test whether a graph is bipartite by using
>   this parity technique to assign vertices to the two subsets U and V,
>   separately within each connected component of the graph, and then
>   examine each edge to verify that it has endpoints assigned to
>   different subsets.

The interesting fact is that independent set is Np-complete and vertex cover too, but verifing if a graph is bipartite is plynomial.

In future, for questions like this, also https://cs.stackexchange.com/ is a great place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**Independent vertex cover = bipartite graph + minimum vertex cover?**On the same problem